# "MyString" values do not cout correctly

Tags: c++, data-structures, hashtable

I have created a class myString, in which I have overloaded operators to use for my hash table. I have the following problem:
In my print function, cout-ing the value works, but cout-ing the key does not. Instead, random characters are printed.

I do not wish to use nodes in this program.

```
void hashTable::print(){
    int i;
    cout<<"-------hash table-------"<<endl;
    cout<<"index    key       value"<<endl;
    MyString key=data[i].getKey();
    int value=data[i].getValue();
    for(i=0;i<length;i++){
        cout<<"     "<<i;
        cout<<"     "<<key;
        cout<<"        "<<value;
        }
    cout<<endl;
}
```

Comment: Can you narrow it down to the minimum amount of code necessary to replicate one problem? Once we've solved one you can ask another question if you still have other issues. Is the main issue that your string class doesn't print or that your hash table doesn't work? Read through [mcve] and work on cleaning this up a bit.

Comment: Sure, I cleaned it up.

Comment: what is `MyString`? we'll at least need the `operator<<` defined for it

Answer (score 4):

In your code, you set `key` and `value` only once at the beginning using an `i` which, since it has not been initialized, has an indeterminate value. You need to get your elements *each* iteration using the proper `i` value.

```
void hashTable::print() {
    cout << "-------hash table-------" << endl;
    cout << "index    key       value" << endl;

    for(int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        MyString key = data[i].getKey();
        int value = data[i].getValue();
        cout << "     " << i;
        cout << "     " << key;
        cout << "        " << value;
    }

    cout << endl;
}
```

Not sure if this totally addresses your problem, but it'll help nonetheless.